# Rename Dataframe name python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I want to change the name of an dataframe using variables.

---

```
db = pd.Dataframe()

sopa = ['cebola','batata']


for sopa_id in sopa: 

    sopa_id = db
```

I want that the output to be:

```
 cebola = db

 batata = db
```

The goal is that each one of the variable get the dataframe name.

Comment: So you want to make two copies of `db` and have one named `cebola` and one to be `batata`?

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic variable names in python, see [How can you dynamically create variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables)

The way to do it is to make a `dictionary` where the `key` is the name and the `value` is the dataframe `db`.
I would discourage dynamic variable names as a general rule though.

```
db = pd.DataFrame()
# -- Do whatever here to populate --
sopa = ['cebola','batata']

dataframeDict = {}
for sopa_id in sopa:
    dataframeDict[sopa_id] = db
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i've got the following result:   "NameError: name 'copy' is not defined"

Comment: Add import line

Comment: i wan't that the new dataframe name came from the loop "for sopa_id in sopa"  where sopa = ['cebola','batata']

Comment: You can simply write: 
cebola = db.copy()
batata = db.copy().
And make sure to capitalize the f in DataFrame not Dataframe

Comment: Why? you can't hardcode that if `sopa` isn't hardcoded. If you want a variable/dynamic variable names then check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables

Answer (score 0):

I start by saying that what you are doing is probably not good practice. This can probably be solved with `dict`.

Anyway I think `locals()` can come in handy.

```py
for i in range(3):
    locals()["var"+str(i)] = i
    
print(var0)
print(var1)
print(var2)
```

As you can see var0, var1 and var2 don't exist before the loop.
You can find more [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, problem solved.

```
db = pd.Dataframe()

sopa = ['cebola','batata']


for sopa_id in sopa: 
    locals()["new_name_is_"+str(sopa_id)] = db
```

best,